# Capture multiple values from textbox and store for PDF creation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to stackoverflow as of today, and I am a novice programmer.  I have learned so much from this community and appreciate any advice or help you can give me.

What I am trying to do is use a web form in asp.net using VB, to store the value of textboxes when the user clicks a button.  I am using itextsharp to create a PDF for an inventory form that will only be used internally within my organization.  What I want to do is program a button that will capture the values of the form, clear the form, and then allow a new entry (for a new line on the inventory sheet).  For example, if we have more than one entry on the inventory sheet, I want to store the values, then  program a button to generate the form.

I really have tried to help myself and am quite proud of my progress so far.  I know I will be able to accomplish this with your help!

Forgive my code as it is not standardized or even commented appropriately yet.

I also understand that I will likely have to rework my program, but I am okay with that.  Currently, the code works for a single line input.  Here is the code

```
    Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim reader As New PdfReader(Server.MapPath("pdfs\InventoryForm.pdf"))
    Dim output As New MemoryStream()
    Dim stamper As New PdfStamper(reader, output)

    Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click


        Dim fromBuilding As String = CStr(ddlFromBuilding.Text)
        Select Case fromBuilding

            Case "Art/Receiving"
                fromBuilding = 220

            Case "Administration"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 221

            Case "Classrooms"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 222

            Case "Ball Fields"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 223

            Case "Business Education"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 224

            Case "West Annex Complex"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 225

            Case "Day Care Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 226

            Case "Gymnasium"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 227

            Case "Guadalupe Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 228

            Case "Carpenter Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 229

            Case "Liberal Arts"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 230

            Case "Learning Resource Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 231

            Case "Life Science"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 232

            Case "Mechanical Plant"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 233

            Case "Ahwatukee - Horizon Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 234

            Case "M&O Storage"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 235

            Case "Music"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 236

            Case "Physical Science"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 237

            Case "Student Services Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 238

            Case "Student Union"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 239

            Case "Classrooms - IKON/Marketing"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 240

            Case "AZ Agricultural Education Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 241

            Case "Student Enrollment Services"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 242

            Case "Performing Arts Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 243

            Case "Library"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 247
        End Select

        Dim toBuilding As String = CStr(ddlToBuilding.Text)
        Select Case toBuilding

            Case "Art/Receiving"
                fromBuilding = 220

            Case "Administration"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 221

            Case "Classrooms"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 222

            Case "Ball Fields"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 223

            Case "Business Education"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 224

            Case "West Annex Complex"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 225

            Case "Day Care Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 226

            Case "Gymnasium"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 227

            Case "Guadalupe Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 228

            Case "Carpenter Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 229

            Case "Liberal Arts"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 230

            Case "Learning Resource Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 231

            Case "Life Science"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 232

            Case "Mechanical Plant"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 233

            Case "Ahwatukee - Horizon Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 234

            Case "M&O Storage"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 235

            Case "Music"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 236

            Case "Physical Science"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 237

            Case "Student Services Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 238

            Case "Student Union"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 239

            Case "Classrooms - IKON/Marketing"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 240

            Case "AZ Agricultural Education Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 241

            Case "Student Enrollment Services"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 242

            Case "Performing Arts Center"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 243

            Case "Library"
                ddlFromBuilding.Text = 247
        End Select

        Dim InventoryAdapter As New DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTableAdapter
        InventoryAdapter.Insert(ReasonForTransfer:=ddlReason.Text, Serial:=txtbxSerialNumber.Text, Tag:=txtbxTagNumber.Text, Description:=txtbxDescription.Text, FromCampus:=txtbxFromCampus.Text, FromBuilding:=fromBuilding, FromRoom:=txtbxFromRoom.Text, ToCampus:=txtbxToCampus.Text, ToBuilding:=ddlToBuilding.Text, ToRoom:=txtbxToRoom.Text, AcceptedBy:=txtbxAcceptedBy.Text, AccepteeEmail:=txtbxAccepteeEmail.Text, ReleasedBy:=txtbxReleasedBy.Text, ReleaseeEmail:=txtbxReleaseeEmail.Text, Notes:=txtbxNotes.Text)
        lblItemAdded.Text = "Item Added Successfully!"
        GridView1.DataBind()


        If ddlReason.Text = "Location Transfer" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbLocation", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "Trade-In/Replacement" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbTradeIn", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "Surplus" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbSurplus", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "Trashed" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbTrashed", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "Cannibalized" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbCannibalized", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "Destroyed/Damaged" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbDestroyed", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "Computer Repair" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbComputerRepair", "Yes")
        ElseIf ddlReason.Text = "External Donation" Then
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("cbExternalDonation", "Yes")
        End If

        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Description1", txtbxDescription.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Tag1", txtbxTagNumber.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Serial1", txtbxSerialNumber.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("FromCampus1", txtbxFromCampus.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("FromBuilding1", fromBuilding)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("FromRoom1", txtbxFromRoom.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ToCampus1", txtbxToCampus.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ToBuilding1", toBuilding)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ToRoom1", txtbxToRoom.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Date", Date.Today())
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ReleaseDate", Date.Today())
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("AcceptedDate", Date.Today())
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ReleasedName", txtbxReleasedBy.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("AcceptedName", txtbxAcceptedBy.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ReleasedSignature", txtbxReleaseeEmail.Text)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("AcceptedSignature", txtbxAccepteeEmail.Text)

        stamper.FormFlattening = True

        stamper.Close()
        reader.Close()

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=InventoryForm.pdf")
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray())
        Response.End()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        ddlReason.SelectedIndex = "0"
        txtbxSerialNumber.Text = ""
        txtbxDescription.Text = ""
        txtbxTagNumber.Text = ""
        ddlToBuilding.SelectedIndex = "0"
        txtbxToCampus.Text = ""
        txtbxToRoom.Text = ""
        ddlFromBuilding.SelectedIndex = "0"
        txtbxFromCampus.Text = ""
        txtbxFromRoom.Text = ""
        txtbxNotes.Text = ""
        lblItemAdded.Text = ""
    End Sub

End Class
```

Even if a solution is not possible to provide, I would greatly appreciate any pointing in the right direction.  Thank you very much for your time!